# Color code email accounts in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2019

is it possible to color code email accounts in Outlook? Not the separate emails, but the accounts!
I have been googling this too, but I cannot find the answer.

Comment: Do you mean conditional formatting? Eg if you get an email from your boss to have it change the subject line to bold and change the colour?

Comment: https://www.techlicious.com/how-to/make-important-email-standout-in-outlook-with-color-coding1/ you can color code emails sent to a specific account.

Comment: No, I really want to give the account a different colour. Not specific emails

Answer (score 1):

I have been using multiple email accounts in Outlook for many years (since Outlook 2002).

There is no ability to color code email Accounts or (in the Account setup  and Profile tools) to color code email Profiles (data files).

Even in Outlook itself, properties of Outlook only allow for colors in Flags and Calendar labels. Main calendar and archive calendars are different colors.

**So  is it possible to color code email accounts in Outlook?**

No, you cannot do this natively in Outlook so far as I know and have experience with.

Answer (score 0):

*Not verified*, no Outlook accessible.

Try inserting a colorized UTF symbol (in the name),
e.g. code points 2648 - 2653 *(hex codes,  so ... 49, 4A, ... 4F, 50 ...)*

*☝ In Linux (where I am at the moment):*
Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> hit <kbd>u</kbd> then type `2648`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>... The first character below appears...

*♈ - Aries, ♉ - Taurus, ♊ - Gemini, ...*